# regular expression to find a number after a substring in python

Tags: python, regex

I have this string:

```
string = "TIC_signal_12 ((task)(0))"
```

by using regular expressions, I want to get the number but just after the "(task)" substring but I do not know how to build the expression

Answer (score 1):

Use `\D*` to match non-digit chars.

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "TIC_signal_12 ((task)(0))"
>>> re.search(r'\(task\)\D*(\d+)', string).group(1)
'0'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a numerous ways to do this with regular expressions.

Here is one with a look-behind

```
import re

string = r"TIC_signal_12 ((task)(0))"
pattern = r"(?<=TIC_signal_12 \(\(task\)\()\d+"


task_number = re.search(pattern, string)

if task_number:
    print(task_number.group(0))
```

Make sure that you check that `task_number` is not None before you use it. In the event that the the string isn't found then `task_number` will be `None` and then it will raise an Exception if you didn't check for `None`